# C++ How to turn off monitor without sleep

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this console app that triggers monitor off by the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>

}
#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")


int main()
{
    ::PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)2);

    system("pause");

return 0;
}
```

It works and basically turns off the display.
However, the system always transition to sleep mode a few seconds (16sec in example below) after the display turns off.
This can be checked by command below

> powercfg.exe /sleepstudy

[image]

Is there a way to only turn off the display and not put the system to sleep?

PS. if display is turned off by OS by video idle timeout, the *exit reason* is *input keyboard* and not transition to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `SetThreadExecutionState` to keep system online. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate

It's work I try this code

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" {
#include <Powrprof.h>

}
#pragma comment(lib, "Powrprof.lib")


int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    ::PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM)2);
    while(true)
    {
        SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
        Sleep(6000);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wait about half of hour.

Comment: Yes I already tried it but system still goes to sleep.

`SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);`

Comment: @JCGM From [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate#remarks), Calling `SetThreadExecutionState` without `ES_CONTINUOUS` simply resets the idle timer; to keep the display or system in the working state, **the thread must call SetThreadExecutionState periodically**.

Comment: @JCGM I updated my answer. You can check it.

Comment: @HancelLin, how did you know it works? I tried it but system still transition to sleep.

Comment: @JCGM Oh, I found my computer was close the sleep feature in power management.